# Асинхронная обработка http запроса в Angular

Tags: javascript, http, angular2, observer

Есть функция в сервисе, которая возвращает Observable объект

```
getRights(callback) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let rights;
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(this.API + 'users/profile', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json().user.rights);
},
```

далее в guard компоненте необходимо вернуть значение исходя из полученного значения через метод getRights() (true или false).
Так вот в чём проблема - вызов return срабатывает до того как приходит ответ от getRights().

```
canActivate() {
    let result;
    this.authService.getRights().subscribe( data => result = data);
    if(result == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Пробовал решить это с помощью callback, но ничего не вышло, значение всё так же приходит позднее чем нужно. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не верен подход к реализации метода *canActivate*. Если смотреть [справку](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)

Сигнатура у функции следующая:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
```

Отсюда видно, что кроме непосредственно *boolean* она может возвращать *Promise* либо *Observable*.

Поэтому в случае в вопросе метод должен был иметь следующий вид:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.authService.getRights();
}
```

При условии что *getRights* вернет `Observable<boolean>` или `Promise<boolean>`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что я с этим могу сделать. В итоге мне надо получить численное значения, которое указывает давать доступ для пользователя или нет.

Comment: @PierreDaque, все очень просто, достаточно сделать, чтобы твой Observable возвращал boolean. Это значение будет показывать - дать доступ или нет. Если для этого тебе надо сделать какое-то сравнение, то сделай это в методе `map`, так же как сейчас в методе `map` ты получаешь сами права

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
canActivate() {
    let result;
    this.authService.getRights()
        .subscribe(data => {
            if(data == 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }), Error => alert(Error);

}
```

Comment: две строки условия можно заменить на `data==0`

Comment: Это не работает, так как вызов return должен быть в canActivate

Comment: Этот фрагмент кода только показывает, как дождаться ответа от сервера.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148941)

Answer (score 0):

Реализация дальнейшей логики должна происходить в [подписчике](https://github.com/pictaile/angular2-example/blob/master/app/auth/auth.component.ts)

Так как запрос выполняется асинхронно, вы должны дождаться когда он выполнится, а выполнится он у Вас когда отработает `subscribe`, соответственно все дальнейшая логика должна быть в этом методе.

Comment: у тебя куда-то не туда ссылка ведет, в указанном файле нет метода canActivate. Ну и старайся, чтобы ответ не заключался _только_ в ссылке

Comment: @Grundy да уже увидел, долго не обновлял потому что сообщение редактировал

Comment: Но у тебя ссылка все еще на _auth.component.ts_ а там нет метода canActivate

Comment: @Grundy у меня по аналогии была getData сделана. Сейчас обновлю гит

Comment: @Grundy обновил репозиторий

Comment: Возможно ты не совсем верно понял вопрос, во втором ангуляре есть отдельный интерфейс с методом canActivate, и его не надо вызывать самостоятельно. Хотя неизвестно как этот метод использует автор

Comment: @Grundy точно, я подумал, что автор делает свой метод

Comment: Но в любом случае он то возвращает Observable
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html, соответственно всё равно приидётся работать через подписчик

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55286/discussion-between-grundy-and-konstantin-okhotnick).